# Onload set divs to visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down with two options 'yes' and 'no' in relation to the question 'Was there a Witness to the Incident?' if option 'yes' is selected then two more questions appear and the option value is then saved in a php value and if 'no' then the two questions are hidden. Which loads fine when the page is refreshed or the form is submitted however if the option is set to 'yes' then two questions load as hidden, and can only be visible if the drop down is set to 'no' and then 'yes' again. What I'm looking for is if it was set to 'yes' then the form is submitted when the page reloads the drop down is still set to 'yes' (which I already have working) and the two questions are visible as well.

Thanks guys,
Matt.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $(function() {
    $('select[name="a18"]').change(function(e) {
      $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
    });
  });
  var witness = '<?php echo $A18 ?>';
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.dropDown {
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
#irMain {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#irMainWitness {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
#irBottomWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainDD {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="irMain">
  <p>Was there a Witness to the Incident?:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainDD">
  <select name="a18" class="dropDown">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Name of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainWitness">
  <textarea name="a19" cols="1" rows="2">
  </textarea>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Contact Number of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irBottomWitness">
  <textarea name="a20" cols="1" rows="2">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The variable 'witness' is set to the option value on form submit. (Still not working)

Code:

```
<script>
    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        $(function() {
            $('select[name="a18"]').change(function(e) {
            $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
            }); 
        }); 

        witness = "<?php echo $savedA18 ;?>";

        if (witness == "Yes"){
            $('select[name="a18"]').val("Yes");
            $('select[name="a18"]').triggerHandler("change");
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Output:

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
        $(function() {
            $('select[name="a18"]').change(function(e) {
            $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
            }); 
        }); 

        witness = "Yes";

        if (witness == "Yes"){
            $('select[name="a18"]').val("Yes");
            $('select[name="a18"]').triggerHandler("change");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you really need to do a full page refresh on form submit?  Most modern apps would do the submit via XHR and update the existing page contents.

Comment: $('select[name="a18"]').change( function(){ /* your function */ }).change();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually trigger the change event after the code where you have set the value to Yes.

```
$('select[name="a18"]').triggerHandler("change");
```

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  
  $('select[name="a18"]').val("Yes");
  $(function() {
    $('select[name="a18"]').change(function(e) {
      $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
    });
  });
  var witness = '<?php echo $A18 ?>';
  
  // set the value on onload
  
  $('select[name="a18"]').val("Yes");
  
  $('select[name="a18"]').triggerHandler("change");
  
  
  
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
textarea {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.dropDown {
  width: 99.5%;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
#irMain {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
#irMainWitness {
  background-color: #ddebf7;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
#irBottomWitness {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
#irQMainDD {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="irMain">
  <p>Was there a Witness to the Incident?:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainDD">
  <select name="a18" class="dropDown">
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Name of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irQMainWitness">
  <textarea name="a19" cols="1" rows="2">
  </textarea>
</div>

<div id="irMainWitness">
  <p>Contact Number of Witness:</p>
</div>

<div id="irBottomWitness">
  <textarea name="a20" cols="1" rows="2">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, this works if I just won't it to be yes all the time not just when the option yes has been selected, I thought maybe use my saved value and set it up like that but I'm not sure I did it correctly as it isn't functioning the way I had planned yet, no error messages either. Any idea?

Comment: @MattHutch how are you setting the value as Yes on page load when you save and refresh the page ?

Comment: Using SQL database, I'm sure this isn't the issue as I used a php echo to check and it was outputting perfectly.

Comment: So are you setting the value in PHP code ??  Could you show that part?

Comment: Okay, So I think I've found the problem but no idea why it's doing it. The drop down is being set to yes still but the css isn't changing the div display?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below, create a function to toggle question divs and call it on page load and call it whenever drop down changes.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var witness = '<?php echo $A18 ?>';
   $.toggleQuestions = function(drpDown){       
     $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle(drpDown.val() == 'Yes');
   };

  $('select[name="a18"]').on("change", function(e) {
    $.toggleQuestions($(this));  
  });

  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $.toggleQuestions($('select[name="a18"]'));  
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
$('select[name="a18"]').change(function(e) {
  $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
});
```

to this:

```
$('select[name="a18"]').change(function(e) {
  $("#irMainWitness,#irQMainWitness,#irBottomWitness").toggle();
});
```

Because the first one only hides and does not show these back.